# FocusGained and FocusLost not working?

Tags: java, awt

Here is my code in the event methods:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vREkJ.png)

```
private void txtCampusSearchFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                            
    this.txtCampusSearch.setText(null);
}                                           

private void txtCampusSearchFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                          
    this.txtCampusSearch.setText("Search...");
}                                         

private void txtBuildingSearchFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                              
    this.txtCampusSearch.setText(null);
}                                             

private void txtBuildingSearchFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                            
    this.txtCampusSearch.setText("Search...");
}
```

However when I actually run the application these methods don't seem to be activated when focus is gained / lost. [Application Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vREkJ.png)

Comment: please add your code to the question and not as image

Comment: Do you know that even in BuildingSearch you set text on campus?

Comment: Haha, I'm an idiot. Thank you! That'll teach me to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a focus listener to your textfield.

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("A TextField");
 textField.addFocusListener(new MyFocusListener());
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html